# String handling in ANSI C

Tags: c, string, path, filesystems

Suppose I receive the following path

```
char* path = "home/directory/file.txt"
```

How could I handle this string to get just `file.txt`'s parent directory to get this

```
"home/directory"
```

I would like to code something that worked this way

```
char* _get_ParentDir(char* file_path);
```

and that this function would return the parent's path.

Comment: just scan from the right and replace the first / with a \0 character. You need a for loop for this.

Comment: @user1095108: No, you just need `strrchr()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thank you very much Keith! so, i should use strrchr() to get the position of the last / and replace it with "\0" ? Is it so?

Comment: @GuillermoGruschka Be careful with replacing, if you are handed a string literal, trying to modify it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you very much for your feedback, I will sure keep it in mind.

Comment: And in fact, that's one of the undefined behaviours that usually cause a segfault, since string literals are often stored in read-only memory.

Comment: Holy crap, does nobody ever learn what's in libc any more? It's called basename(3), and is, IIRC, part of POSIX. Why does everybody feel the need to roll their own every time a simple problem is encountered? And do it badly, at that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't give your function a name starting with an underscore.  Such identifiers are reserved to the implementation.

Based on your description, you can just replace the last `/` character with a null character:

```
char *last_slash = strrchr(path, '/');
if (last_slash != NULL) {
    *last_slash = '\0';
}
```

That modifies the string in place -- but you want a function.  Writing a function that returns a pointer to a string is tricky; you have to worry about allocating the space for the string. There are three common approaches:

1. Declare a `static` array in your function, and return a pointer to its first element. Problem: every call to the function will clobber the buffer used by any previous calls.
2. Have the caller pass a pointer to a buffer into which the result is written. This makes things more complex for the caller.
3. Have the function allocate the buffer using `malloc()` (and be sure to check for allocation failures). This works, but it makes the caller responsible for `free()`ing the buffer later.

Your system may also provide a function that does this for you. Another answer mentions a `dirname()` function in `<libgen.h>`. That's specified by POSIX, but not by the C standard; your system may or may not have it. You should read the man page (`man 3 dirname` if you're on a Unix-like system), particularly the NOTES section.

Comment: ...or in this specific case, you can just return the number of characters in the prefix of the string that comprises the parent dir name.

Comment: @KeithThompson: 100% understood! Regarding the responsability of free()ing the buffer, I am still not sure of how is this going to be handled. This function will be used as a parameter for other functions, so thats why I need it to return the string itself. Supose i will delete a file from a directory, and i want to update the father directory, I will do something like (dummy names) updateFather(get_ParentDir(file));

Comment: Names beginning with an underscore are fine. The names reserved for the implementation are those beginning with an underscore followed by another underscore or a capital letter.

Comment: @ThomSmith: C standard, 7.1.3p1: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
underscore are always reserved for any use. All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces." You *can* use some identifiers starting with underscores in some contexts, but it's much easier just to avoid them.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Regarding where lays the responsability for free()ing the buffer, suposing I use it as a parameter for other functions as explained in my previous comment, what would you suggest? Thank you very much for your help! I was really stuck at this.

Comment: @GuillermoGruschka: Typically the caller is responsible for `free()`ing it. Of course it should do so only after it's no longer being used. It's easy to get this kind of thing wrong -- which is why higher-level languages often do automatic garbage collection. In C, you just have to be careful. Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if you run into problems.

Comment: 1: It's also not thread-safe. 2: It also risks buffer overflow. If passing a buffer, you must also pass a length, or have a pre-defined max length. Method 4: Just return the length of the directory prefix. This requires that the directory path *is* a simple prefix of the file path -- you would need something like returning 0 for the directory prefix of a simple file name. "garbage collection" -- or reference counting.

Comment: I really like the "return the prefix length" method. That makes it very flexible, so the caller can decide how best to use the information. In many cases that might mean overwriting the slash in-place, but it could also mean calling a function like `strndup` or even something as simple as `printf("dir: %.*s\n", (int)returned_len, pathname);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* bname=path;
bname+=strlen(path);
while (bname>path && bname[-1]!='\\' && bname[-1]!='/')
   --bname;
```

There is also the basename() function, but my version works for both DOS and Unix/Linux paths.

*[Edit: I'd like to mention that I posted the following line by itself at approximately the same time as Ernest Friedman-Hill posted his comment below.  After that, I went on to post the rest of my answer. -phonetagger]*
Oops...  I read your problem backwards.  You want the dirname() function.  `#include <libgen.h>`

Or....

```
const char* dname = strdup(path);
const char* bname = dname;
if (dname)
{
   bname+=strlen(path);
   while (bname>dname && bname[-1]!='\\' && bname[-1]!='/')
      --bname;
   if (bname != dname)
      bname[-1] = '\0';
   else
   {
      bname = path;
      free(dname);
      dname = NULL;
   }
}
```

Note that this version allocates a new string for dname, which you may or may not want to free(), depending on the life you need it to have.  If you need it for the duration of your application's execution, there's no need to free() it at all, the OS will automatically reclaim your process's entire virtual address space on application exit.

Also note that the strdup() is necessary, as your assignment of char* path is from a static const string initializer, which is most likely allocated in a read-only section of your program (perhaps .rodata, depending on your compiler).

Comment: Technically your version doesn't work *at all*, since at the end of this, the user still doesn't have a pointer to the directory path, which is what he wanted. I'll remove the downvote if you fix it up to provide the actual directory path.

Comment: strdup can return NULL. And bname>path is undefined. And dname = NULL leaks memory.

Comment: OK, I am appropriately spanked.

Comment: There... that should fix it.  Guess I got a bit careless!

Answer (score 1):

Just sticking a '\0' at the last slash has a possibly unintended side-effect on the original string. to avoid this, you will need to create another string:

```
char* _get_ParentDir(char* file_path) {
    char *c = strrchr(file_path, "/");
    long n = c - file_path;
    char *dir = malloc(n+1); // this will need to be freed later
    dir[n] = 0;
    memcpy(dir, file_path, n);
    return dir;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the responsability of free()ing the buffer, I am still not sure of how is this going to be handled. This function will be used as a parameter for other functions, so thats why I need it to return the string itself. Supose i will delete a file from a directory, and i want to update the father directory, I will do something like (dummy names) updateFather(get_ParentDir(file));

Comment: malloc can return NULL. Also, strncpy is rarely the right solution for anything. Its flaws are avoided here, but memcpy is more straightforward and faster (considerably so on some architectures).

Comment: `strrchr` does not return an integer.